# How to keep manifest and exclude POM from JAR?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-jar-plugin

Found that I can exclude ***pom.xml*** from final jar using:

```
<archive>
   <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
</archive>
```

But this exclude the xml and the pom.properties is there a way to keep only pom.properties?

thx

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done using the conventional methods in maven.

Although, when you execute the maven goal (`install, package...`), the `pom.properties` is created at the following location:

`target\maven-archiver\pom.properties`

You can explicitly include this resource in your archive by modifying the jar/war plugin configuration.